Why was "To Kill a Mockingbird" used as a book safe in "The Game"?
In the movie The Game (1997), the protagonist carries the book To Kill a Mockingbird.
He breaks into his house when it's up for auction and takes this book with him, from what I believe is his library.
I know he carried a gun in it, but why did the makers of the movie choose this book? It could have been a book with no name, just to serve the purpose of keeping a gun. So, why is the name of this book shown?
Is it a reference to something?

Based on the question content shouldn't the title be: Why 'To Kill a Mockingbird' was used as a book safe in The Game? The current title suggests that the question is about why the book is being carried by the protagonist during the film, not why this particular book was used by the film makers.

Thank you. I edited the title.

David Fincher offered some explanation in his audio commentary for the movie. In brief he thinks that;

Real life book safes tend to have public domain titles.

That someone who owns a book safe would want the book to have a memorable title (to make it easier to locate on a shelf full of other books in an emergency).

As a filmmaker, he wanted to choose a title the audience would be familiar with.

He liked the way the prop looked (with the raised gold lettering), suggesting this is a real 'book safe' that they purchased, not one that was custom-made for the film.

There's something about that in in this home, you know I've got one of those, one of those book safes, [and] they usually they come with sort of different titles on them that you can get in and they're usually semi-famous and they're usually in the public domain. I think To Kill a Mockingbird is in the public domain. We were looking for some title that would be memorable, you know if you if you actually hid a .357 magnum somewhere in your in your house you'd want to be able to recall at a moment's notice what the title of the book was, so it would have to be something that people know and it was a nice one to sort of see in gold leaf on the side of, that it just looked good.
[edited for readability]




To Kill a Mockingbird is most certainly not in the public domain. It was written in 1960 by an author who died in 2016; US copyright term is either 70 years from author's death (2086), or 95 years from publication (2055). On the other hand, the title of a work probably isn't subject to copyright; maybe trademark and other restrictions would apply, but that would probably just make the rule "don't use titles from extremely litigious right-holders like the Tolkien estate".

@IMSoP the title would most definitely be covered by copyright like the rest of the book (if someone wrote a book with the same title or something very close to it it could be an issue for them), but fair use or similar exceptions depending on jurisdiction would probably apply in this case.

@jcaron A quick search online turns up numerous articles confirming my suspicion that a book title is not sufficiently distinctive to attract copyright protection, e.g. https://www.writersdigest.com/publishing-faqs/can-you-use-a-book-title-thats-been-used-before https://copyrightservice.co.uk/services/knowledge-base/kb_title https://www.liveabout.com/can-a-book-title-be-copyrighted-3974593 As those articles say, there are other protections which the author or their estate might enforce, around "passing off" and trademarks; but they would have no chance of suing for copyright violation.

@jcaron I found this slightly more nuanced article which suggests that in principle a title might be protected by copyright "if it meets the originality requirement". So theoretically, the estate of Harper Lee could sue you claiming that the four words "To Kill a Mockingbird" were an "intellectual creation"; but it would be an unusual and contested case.
